# На каком языке(-ах) программирования написана ВЕБ-версия Telegram, WhatsApp, Viber, Signal и Zoom?

Tags: веб-программирование, telegram, viber, whatsapp, zoom

На каком языке(-ах) программирования написана ВЕБ-версия следующих продуктов:

1. Telegram
2. WhatsApp
3. Viber
4. Signal
5. Zoom
   P.S. В Интернете искал ответ, но там не нашёл на каком языке(-ах) программирования создана именно серверная часть (бэкенд).

Comment: Думаю это знают только программисты из этих компаний

Comment: Наверное js,php